# Get the list of users that liked a post

Tags: javascript, php, instagram-api

A friend of mine decided to run a sweepstakes on Instagram without giving much thought to how to get the full list of users that liked a post. He's saying he can just pick a random user from the available/visible list, but that wouldn't be fair, so I decided to step in.

The post in question, currently, has 1.4k likes.

First, I created a tiny script in JS to view, scroll down (to populate the list) and finally get the users that liked the post. This was troublesome to create, but it works. Then I realized I could not view all the users. While there are 1.4k users, I could only list 675 of them.

In the name of fairness, this is not enough. So I started digging more and examined the HTTP Requests made by the (Instagram) post page to the Instagram Graph API to load more users. This is what the URL looks like:

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=SOME_ID&variables={\"shortcode\":\"SHORTCODE\",\"first\":20}
```

When I make a request to this URL, I get the following:

```
{
    "data": {
        "shortcode_media": {
            "id": "SOME_ID",
            "shortcode": "SHORTCODE",
            "edge_liked_by": {
                "count": 675,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": false,
                    "end_cursor": "AQBPkM1xm2XgBx8ZQ8lR6GDsFAvQBx_Eqxg2NnTXN-GUPGhlpUa9_10UoMcJ6xNcIH4"
                },
                "edges": [{
                    "node": {
                        "id": "", // value omitted intentionally
                        "username": "", // value omitted intentionally
                        "full_name": "", // value omitted intentionally
                        "profile_pic_url": "", // value omitted intentionally
                        "is_verified": false,
                        "followed_by_viewer": false,
                        "requested_by_viewer": false
                    }
                },
                ...
```

There's this `["edge_liked_by"]["count"]` property and it is set to `675`. I'm guessing this is a server-side restriction. When I increase the `"first"` parameter in the URL and make it greater than 675, it still returns 675 users.

Can I overcome this restriction and get the full list in any way?

---

**Update**: I've just tried the same thing with comments. The post has 11.8k comments and this is what the request returns:

```
{
    "data": {
        "shortcode_media": {
            "edge_media_to_comment": {
                "count": 11809,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": true,
                    "end_cursor": "AQBV53OxNFkaHwJ6xjgHmlI-hwtpHCEeButMmGLwZJ_sjdyUy49gY_WZo1iH_aRcuAFOCzfrKPEktMaQLRjFVAsmQTincJpr4ZTITbTT1BZkJQ"
                },
                "edges": [{
                    "node": {
                        "id": "",
                        "text": "",
                        "created_at": ,
                        "owner": {
                            "id": "",
                            "profile_pic_url": "",
                            "username": ""
                        }
                    }
                },
                ...
```

The exact count of the comments is `11809` and the request listed first `10259`, but there's a next page. So I requested the next page and this is it:

```
{
    "data": {
        "shortcode_media": {
            "edge_media_to_comment": {
                "count": 11809,
                "page_info": {
                    "has_next_page": false,
                    "end_cursor": null
                },
                "edges": [{
                    "node": {
                        "id": "",
                        "text": "",
                        "created_at": ,
                        "owner": {
                            "id": "",
                            "profile_pic_url": "",
                            "username": ""
                        }
                    }
                },
                ...
```

This time it didn't return the remaining 1550 (11809 - 10259) users, but just 356 of them. And there's no next page. So there seems to be some inconsistencies. (Perhaps, there's a privacy issue that prevents some users to be listed?)

Comment: `has_next_page` = false nope

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `"has_next_page"` is `true` when I request less than the `"count"` (675). When I request 675 or greater, it is set to `false`. While I agree that most of it is hidden, I don't think I can get the full list with the current parameters. I need a different request URL or a parameter to override `"count"`. Though, I'm not sure if these exist.